# Spring OAuth2 refresh token is going to authenticate the user again

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, jwt, angular5, spring-security-oauth2

I am sending request to server for getting new access token by using refresh token but there is call going to authenticate and I think it shout not authenticate as  user is already authenticated. I just need a new access token by using refresh token

Request is as follow:

```
private authorization = btoa("Client-Id:Client-secret");
  private headers = new Headers({"Authorization": "Basic " + this.authorization,
                "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"});

const body = "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token="+ refresh_token;
```

Sending it to the "oauth/token" mapping.

What is the solution that user should not go to authenticate.

Thanks.

Comment: You use the client credentials grant type. How does user involve in this scenario? Do you refer the user to the client? Those are two different entities in oauth context